# WebBrowser DocumentText cannot navigate javascript without giving full path

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

When I try to pass my Html into WebBrowser.DocumentText which include JS.

```
<script src="jquery\script.js">&#160;</script>
```

It is same path with my executable. But when open in Winform, it is unable to find the 'script.js'..

But when you enter the full path of script, it is working.

```
StreamReader stringReader = new StreamReader(htmlFilename, Encoding.Default);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string temp;
while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(temp = stringReader.ReadLine()))
{
   sb.AppendLine(temp);
}
stringReader.Close();
return sb.ToString();
```

Eventually I read html into StringBuilder, and pass it to WebBrowser.DocumentText. Any other way to make it works without giving full path of the script?

Answer (score 0):

You can give like this into your HTML document

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery\script.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is not working. Although didn't prompt any error and there is source, but the page is blank...

Comment: Javascript file is in executable path(Example \bin\Release\jquery\script.js). am i correct?

Comment: Yeah, u are right. But actually I pass all codes in HTML into String Builder, I think that's why it is not able to find the path...

Comment: Can you see the Another answer which I was post now? It may be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

in HTML Page

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src={Fullpath}></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

in C#

```
 string ScriptfullPath = Application.StartupPath.ToString()+"\\jquery\\script.js";;
        string htmlContent;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath +  \\JQuery\\sample.htm"))
        {
            htmlContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        htmlContent = htmlContent.Replace("{Fullpath}", ScriptfullPath);
```

Then your HTML document will use Script file with full path...

Comment: It is a good idea... However, there is limitation for my case that I cannot change any code in C# project... By the way, it is a good solution